# How to access extended properties in Identity in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Feeling a bit stuck: I am able to add properties to ApplicationUser thusly:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
        public string CustomUserName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]       
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; } 
    }
```

And they show up in my Register.cshtml view, and get added to the database just fine via the Register method. So far, I'm using the default setup that is provided by dotnet core, with Identity.

The problem is how to access them once they're in there. UserManager has some default methods, like `GetEmailAsync`, but what is the process for getting my other, newly added, properties?

I thought about using an extension method, but as I dig deeper into the original source code (to try to imitate what `GetEmailAsync` does) I admit to getting a bit lost in [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/7fbc36c56684769d3535cf1dfd1cddf88fb26343/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs), and I'm not sure if I should do it that way in any case.

I've also looked around and nothing seems to do this part. There are examples of how to add the properties to the Registration, but nobody says how to retrieve them once they're in there.

So what is the best way to get at my newly minted properties?

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The `UserManager<TUser>` class is a generic class. As you can see, you will need an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`.

The `UserManager<TUser>` class exposes the method `Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)` which in your case will return an instance of `ApplicationUser`.

so all you need to do is call `ApplicationUser myUser = myUserManager.FindByIdAsync("myUserId");`